# How to get session id in socket.io 2.0.3?

Tags: express, socket.io

I want to make it so that socket.io only allows 1 connection from the same session at a time. How would I access the session id?

```
var express      = require("express"),
app              = express(),
http             = require("http").Server(app),
io               = require("socket.io")(http),

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unique identifier for the session is `socket.id` base of [this documnet](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-id)

```
var express      = require("express"),
app              = express(),
http             = require("http").Server(app),
io               = require("socket.io")(http),

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    console.log(socket.id);
});
```